# Bash recolour all svg files in directories

Tags: linux, bash, dictionary, svg

Does anyone know how to recolor all of the svg files that would be found in this project?

https://github.com/twain47/Open-SVG-Map-Icons/blob/master/tools/recolour.sh

I have no experience with bash and very little with linux but it seems to me you just need to walk the svg directories and run the recolour.sh but this is all Greek to me.

If this is too specific a question please remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this from the project root. Feel free to switch the colors as needed.

```
find . -name '*.svg' | while read filename; do
    tools/recolour.sh $filename '#FF0000' '#00FF00' '#0000FF' | sponge $filename
done
```

Alternatively, if you cannot figure out how to get the sponge command:

```
find . -name '*.svg' | while read filename; do
    tmpfile=$(mktemp -t temp)
    tools/recolour.sh $filename '#FF0000' '#00FF00' '#0000FF' > $tmpfile
    mv $tmpfile $filename
done
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  All of the files simply become filled in with black.  

sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unknown option to `s'
sed: read error on stdin: Is a directory
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'

are the errors that occur.

Comment: I'm attempting to guess at this a bit.  The hex color codes you gave, I attempted to prepend a '#' sign to no avail.  am I missing something?

Comment: Got it, just needed to add \# to the hex color codes and everything worked great.  I'll adjust my question and accept.

Comment: @user2088672 You are correct, the `#` was left out by me accidentally.